# C++ How is this not member function pointer?

Tags: c++, type-traits

According to following test this:

```
std::cout << std::is_member_function_pointer<int A::*()>::value << std::endl;
```

Is not member function pointer, but regular function, while this:

```
std::cout << std::is_member_function_pointer<int (A::*)()>::value << std::endl;
```

evaluates to true. I tried both with gcc & msvc. What is difference between these two declarations? Are these results correct? Why are parenthesis around `A::*` important?

Comment: Operator precedence. Sorry I first posted this comment as a sarcastic question. No coffee yet. :( Hope that helps. Note that C++ grammar only defines precedence *implicitly*, as a consequence of the grammar rules. But there is an effective precedence overall.

Comment: Even with precedence, what does int A::*() actually mean?

Comment: Looks to me like a function that returns a member pointer.

Comment: Do you get the same if you apply brackets like `(int A::*)()`? Is it the same (check with `typeid`)?

Comment: When I pass (int A::*)() into typeid i get an error - expected an expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences of differently parenthesized type expressions, stem from the operator precedence.

Here is one way to get a more detailed, descriptive specification of a type:

```
C:\my\forums\so\120> echo struct A{}; using T = int A::*(); T o; int x = o; >1.cpp

C:\my\forums\so\120> g++ -c 1.cpp
1.cpp:1:48: error: invalid conversion from 'int A::* (*)()' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
 struct A{}; using T = int A::*(); T o; int x = o;
                                                ^

C:\my\forums\so\120> _
```

<del>So, we see that a variable of type `int A::*()` has the type `int A::* (*)()`.</del>

**EDIT**: I cannot delete this post while it's marked as solution, so for the record: in the above code `o` is not a variable. Instead it's a *function declaration*. `int A::*()` is directly a function type, namely a function returning a data member pointer.

<sup>Now heading for coffee…</sup>

Comment: This is declarators, not operators

Comment: @M.M I mentioned operator precedence because that's how the C syntax is built, with declarations mimicking usage. I didn't even think about it. :) Formally you're right but that's a less practically useful view.

Answer (score 5):

`int A::*()` is type of function, which returns `A`'s member with type `int`, takes no arguments. So it's not member function pointer, even not function pointer.

```
std::cout << std::is_member_function_pointer<int A::*()>::value << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << std::is_pointer<int A::*()>::value << std::endl;                 // 0
std::cout << std::is_function<int A::*()>::value << std::endl << std::endl;   // 1
```

And parentheses change the precedence, `int (A::*)()` is type of `A`'s member function pointer, which returns `int` and takes no arguments.

Comment: This answer seems correct (as opposed to my original answer which included a bit of nonsense :( ).